# How to reverse added percentage to a number

Tags: percentages

Firstly sorry for my bad English.

---

Assume I have some values like this:

```
109
5450
926500
etc...
```

I know all of these values already added with 9% like this :

```
100 + 9         (9      is 9% of 100)   = 109
5000 + 450      (450    is 9% of 5000)  = 5450
850000 + 76,500 (76500 is 9% of 850000) = 926500
```

**What I want?**

I need a formula to give it a value then return the value without `9%`

For instance:

I give it `109` and return me `100`

or

I give it `5450` and return me `5000`

Any ideas?

Comment: Just multiply by $100/109$...

Comment: Note that I don't have `100`. I only have `109`

Comment: That's all you need to do.

Comment: I don't get that! please show me an example for `5450`. How do I get `5000` from `5450` ? (Note that I only have `5450`)

Comment: $5450×100÷109=5000$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on what was said on the comments, multiplying by $\frac{100}{109} $ works for all values. The fact that you happen to have a $109$ in your example was just a mere coincidence.

The way it works is: you have a value $V $. $9$% of it is just $0.09V $. If you add it to the original value you get

$$V + 0.09V = 1V + 0.09V = (1+0.09)V = 1.09V$$

All the values you have are $1.09V $ and you want to find the $V $. All you have to do is divide by $1.09$.

For example,  $5450/1.09 = 5000$. But dividing by $1.09$ is the same as multiplying by $100/109$.

Answer (score 1):

As Parcly Taxel says, multiply the larger value by the fraction $100/109$ to get the smaller value.

Equivalently, divide by $1.09$. (This is a single step on any calculator.)

Edit: For your example, $5450/1.09=5000$.

Comment: Worked like a charm.